# Spring injection: @MockBean @Repository is not injected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm trying to `@MockBean` a `@Repository` annotated class:

```
@Repository
public interface ApplicationDao extends MongoRepository<Application, String> {}
```

I'm injecting it into a `@Service` annotated class:

```
@Service
public class AuthorizationService {

    private ApplicationDao appsDao;
    private List<Application> allowedApplications;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationService(ApplicationDao appsDao) {
        this.appsDao = appsDao;   //<<MOCKED INJECTED BEAN>>
        this.fillApplications();
    }

    private void fillApplications() {
        this.appsDao.findAll()    //<<MOCKED method>>
           .forEach(entry -> {
            this.allowedApplications.put(entry.getName(), entry);
        });
    }

    public bool isAuthorized(Application application) {
        return this.allowedApplications
          .stream()
          .anyMatch(app -> app.getId().equals(application.getId()));
    }
}
```

My test mocking configuration looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
public class GroupReferencesTest {

    private @Autowired AuthorizationService;
    private @MockBean ApplicationDao applicationDao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        Application testApplication = new Application();
        testApplication.setName("test-application");
        List<Application> allowedApplications = new ArrayList<Application>();
        allowedApplications.add(testApplication);

        Mockito
            .when(this.applicationDao.findAll())
            .thenReturn(allowedApplications);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Application app = new Application();
        app.getId("test-application"); 
        assertTrue(this.authorizationService.isAuthorized(app));  //<<FAILS>>
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, my mocked object is not injected. I mean, when my `AuthorizationService` calls its injected `ApplicationDao` is returns an empty list instead of my mocked list.

I've tried to use `@MockBean(name="applicationDao")` as well. The behavior is the same.

I've also tried to configure my mocked bean using this code:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class RestTemplateTestConfiguration {

    @Bean("applicationDao")
    @Primary
    public static ApplicationDao mockApplicationDao() {
        ApplicationDao mock = Mockito.mock(ApplicationDao.class);

        Application testApplication = new Application();
        testApplication.setName("test-application");
        List<Application> allowedApplications = new ArrayList<Application>();
        allowedApplications.add(testApplication);

        Mockito
            .when(mock.findAll())
            .thenReturn(allowedApplications);

        return mock;
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't works right.

`Application` class is:

```
public class Application {
    private String id;

    //setters & getters
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: the first test class doesn't show the whole thing : how the class under test is instantiated ?

Comment: I referred to  the GroupReferencesTest class.

Comment: in `GroupReferencesTest` you never invoke the object under test. You just mock

Comment: Did you try adding `@Repository` annotation on implementation class rather than interface?

Comment: I don't quite figure out what you mean...

Comment: The test fails cause you compare Application by id and didn't set it for mocked data. Regarding the second scenario, remove static keyword from bean method.

Comment: Since it doesn't throw `NullPointerException`, the mock is injected. Try to use MockitoBDD instead, the one is provided by Spring Test starter.

Answer (score 2):

First things first - the type of test. Answer: Unit test.

You are starting Spring context that manages a lifecycle of `AuthorizationService` and then you are trying to inject mock. What really happens is that Spring IoC container is injecting a real `ApplicationDao` (the one managed by Spring IoC container) into the `AuthorizationService`.

**Solution:**

Manage lifecyle of `AuthorizationService` by your test runner (like `MockitoJUnitRunner` and inject `ApplicationDao` mock into it):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GroupReferencesTest {

    private @InjectMocks AuthorizationService authorizationService;
    private @Mock ApplicationDao applicationDao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        Application testApplication = new Application();
        testApplication.setName("test-application");
        List<Application> allowedApplications = new ArrayList<Application>();
        allowedApplications.add(testApplication);

        Mockito
            .when(this.applicationDao.findAll())
            .thenReturn(allowedApplications);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Application app = new Application();
        app.getId("test-application"); 
        assertTrue(this.authorizationService.isAuthorized(app));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've simplified all these classes. In my project, all these classes have more dependencies I showed on post. I need to start tests with `SpringRunner` in order to inject all other dependencies. I don't understand how it's not working. It's a very straightforward example.

Answer (score 2):

Working example

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {AuthorizationService.class})
public class GroupReferencesTest {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorizationService;

    @MockBean
    private ApplicationDao applicationDao;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //given
        Mockito.when(applicationDao.findAll()).thenReturn(emptyList());

        //when & then
        assertTrue(authorizationService.isAuthorized(app));
    }
}
```